# $resource:badcfg error following save

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service module that POSTs data for me:

```
//services.js
var myServices = angular.module('myServices', ['ngResource']);

myServices.factory('User', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource('/signup');
}]);
```

and my controller:

```
//controllers.js
var myControllers = angular.module('myControllers', []);

myControllers.controller('UserController', ['$scope', 'User', function($scope, User) {

    $scope.register = function() {
      User.save($scope.user);
      $scope.user = "";
      alert("User Added"); //for testing
    };
}]);
```

The form data for the user that is registering is POSTed fine and my nodejs server returns a response but looking in the console there is an error when everything has completed:

**Error: [$resource:badcfg] object - http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.12/$resource/badcfg?p0=array**

Any help would be great

Comment: If you throw it into a fiddle I could definitely help. What is the deal with the empty object in User.save({} ?

Comment: I'm not sure actually - This is the first time I've shifted my code into a service block and during my research found the empty object part. Do I need it at all?

Comment: Nope. You don't. I believe that is what is being posted to the server, take it out, and leave the $scope.user. You can check your console in the network tab to see what data is being posted, I bet it is an empty object.

Comment: The response body is static json - just for testing purposes

Comment: `res.send([{name: "user1"}, {name: "user2"}]);`

Comment: Try what @ZackArgyle suggested in modifying your `save` call, and use the Network tab in dev tools to inspect both the request *and* response bodies to/from the server. You might find something unexpected.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that I've changed the `save` call but still the same error - posts fine, response received, then when I click the alert box button the error then appears

Comment: I see the problem, I think. Answer to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$resource`, by default, doesn't expect an array response from a `save` call, which seems to be what you're returning from your server.

You can return a configured $resource object that will expect an array response from `save` like so:

```
myServices.factory('User', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource('/signup', {}, {
        'save': {method:'POST', isArray: true}
    })
}]);
```